# Event Handler for API call

Tags: vba, api, ms-access, events, handler

We are using an old version of Zoiper Biz that uses an old api, not the current zoiper one. I am trying to code a handler, in Ms Access vba, that when zoiper rings, the handler will give the caller id that can then be used to call up the customer details and display them in a form.

The problem I am having, is telling the handler to listen for a change to the API's OnLineStateEvent. I can use the API to make a call from the database and I can use the API to answer the call, I just cannot find a way to trap the caller id.

The passage from the API documentation that relates to OnLineStateEvent is as follows:

OnLineStateEvent - (line: integer; state: TLineState; accountname: string;
format: TCodecs; callerid: string; releasecause: integer) - the line state
event is fired when a line changes its state and provides the line, the new
state, the account used for the call, the format that is used for the call,
the callerid and the release cause if the new state is lsDown.

TLineState as as follows:

TLineState - this enum type is used to hold one of the line state constants and
represents the current state of a given line. It is used with the information
events and cannot be set to a line.

⇒ The Line state constants are as follows:
• lsDown - there is no call on the line. Also indicates that a call has ended.
• lsDialing - the line is dialing but still no meaningful state.
• lsActive - the line is active i.e. has voice activity from the remote side
(probably IVR or some server side ringing sounds), but the call is not
answered.
• lsRinging - there is an incoming call on the line.
• lsWaitForAnswer - the outgoing call is ringing on the remote side.
• lsUp - the call is on, both sides are hearing each other. This is the only
call state that can be transferred and put on hold.
• lsResolvingPort - resolving STUN port.

I have attempted to write a class called Zoiper to handle the line state event.

```
Option Explicit
Public Event LineStatus(ByVal state As String, ByVal callerid As String)

Public Ring As String
Public ThisCallerID As String

Public Function MyEventHandler(state, callerid)
    If state = "IsRinging" Then
        ThisCallerID = callerid
    End If
    MyEventHandler = ThisCallerID
    RaiseEvent LineStatus(state, callerid)
End Function
```

The calling function is as follows:

```
Private Sub cmdAnswer_Click()
Stop
Set il = CreateObject("idefisk.IdefiskAPI")
Dim Listener As Zoiper
Set Listener = New Zoiper

With Listener
    .MyEventHandler(state, callerid) = il.OnLineStateEvent(state, callerid)
End With

If Listener.Ring = "IsRinging" Then
    Me.txtCallerNumber = Listener.ThisCallerID
End If

'il.answer 0

End Sub
```

cmdAnswer_click falls over when it gets to .MyEventHandler(state, callerid) = il.OnLineStateEvent(state, callerid) with object does not support this property or method, which I guess is relating to the il.OnLineStateEvent(state, callerid).

il.Answer 0 is remmed out as I don't want it to answer the call until I have sorted this out.

I have changed so many lines of code so much that I cannot remember what I have tried and what I haven't.
If anyone could please point me in the right direction I would be so grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with the API, nor I have the API installed, so this is just a suggestion.

Try to build a wrapper around Zoiper and listen to its `OnLineStateEvent`. Then if the `state` is `lsRinging`, raise the wrapper's event in order to update the UI.

**Important:**
You need to replicate the `TLineState` enum as per the api's documentation. The values should match in order to be able to compare the state.

In this example, I haven't defined any values, so `lsDown` equals to 0, `lsDialing` equals to 1 etc, but as I said, the numeric values behind the enum should match the api in order to be able to compare them.

The `TLineState` enum:

```
Public Enum TLineState
    lsDown
    lsDialing
    lsActive
    lsRinging
    lsWaitForAnswer
    lsUp
    lsResolvingPort
End Enum
```

Our wrapper class.

```
Option Explicit
Public Event RingingEvent(ByVal calledId As Long)

Private WithEvents objZoiper As Zoiper

' Zoiper OnLineStateEvent.
' Listen to it and raise our RingingEvent if the state is 'lsRinging'
Private Sub objZoiper_OnLineStateEvent(ByVal state As TLineState, ByVal callerid As Long)
    If state = TLineState.lsRinging Then
        RaiseEvent RingingEvent(callerid)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set objZoiper = New Zoiper
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set objZoiper = Nothing
End Sub
```

The form which our wrapper class resides.

Create an instance of the wrapper class when the form loads, and destroy it when it closes. You can change that behavior as per your needs.

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents objWrapper As ZoiperWrapper

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set objWrapper = New ZoiperWrapper
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Close()
    Set objWrapper = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub objWrapper_RingingEvent(ByVal calledId As Long)
    txtCallerNumber.Value = calledId
End Sub
```

Comment: Kostas K. I am very grateful for the trouble you have taken over this. The code I am using to dial out from Zoiper, which works fine, is as follows:
```
Set il = CreateObject("idefisk.IdefiskAPI")
strTarget = txtTelNo
il.Dial txtTelNo, ""
```
However, I do not think my Zoiper class is correct and we are making no mention of the Idefisk.IdefiskAPI anywhere in the code to find the caller number. If the Wrapper Class is dependent on the Zoiper Class being correct, I have a feeling that that is where the problem is.

Comment: In the Wrapper Class that I have called ZoiperWrapper should the 
```
Private WithEvents objZoiper As Zoiper
be
Private WithEvents objZoiper As Idefisk.IdefiskAPI
```
I am just so confused. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API to be honest with you, I just wanted to point out that you need to create an instance of the object and listen to its events. Then the wrapper should raise an event for the view to be updated. Try changing to `Idefisk.IdefiskAPI` and see if that works.

Comment: The wrapper in just a middle man between the UI and the API. Send commands to dial but also capture and propagate events the API raises.